# My desktop restarts every 5 seconds after enabling secure boot

Tags: motherboard

I recently wanted to see if my computer could run Windows 11 and I enabled secure boot and saved the settings that's it.

But now, it just keeps on restarting every 5 seconds without showing anything on the screen.

My motherboard is a GIGABYTE GA-H110M-S2
PROCESSOR INTEL I3 7100
INTERGRATED GRAPHICS
1X4 GB DDR4 RAM
I've tried removing all drives and booting the pc
Removed the ram and placing it again
Reseting bios
I think my bios is dead i ask the technician he said I had to change the mobo.

Comment: You "enabled secure boot and saved the settings and that's it", but you don't say you installed Windows 11, but your title says this is a "Windows 11" system. Further you say nothing shows on the screen. So is Windows 11 installed? Have you cleared your BIOS?

Comment: No I didn't install windows 11 and I cleared my bios 5-6 times and still it restarts every 5 sec

Comment: So you are running Windows 10 then?  What video card do you have?

Comment: Integrated graphics

Comment: In my experience, this issue was caused by RAM becoming dislodged from its slot. Check that it is seated properly

Comment: I removed everything cleant it and yes I check that several times if its seated properly.

Comment: Q: Have you tried to start the PC without any drive? After you clear your BIOS do you give him time to start? Sometimes it takes quite some time and restarts to finally get there. You could update your post and write everything you have tried, so that we can exclude those steps.

Comment: I removed all my drives and reseted my bios .I only had my keyboard mouse and vga connected. I kept it for half an hour running but the results are same.It keeps restarting.

Comment: How did you reset BIOS? Try clearing the CMOS settings by shorting the two pins on mobo by say a metallic object like a screw driver for about 5 - 10 seconds when PC is completely off. After that see if it boots to Firmware (UEFI) and is stable. Then if so, load setup defaults. Mostly now Secure Boot would have been disabled. Then boot to Windows. If all is ok, see if there's a Firmware update for the board and update the BIOS/UEFI and then check if Secure Boot stably works or not.

Comment: After clearing cmos it still restarts and does not show bios